# Getting notification on data updated at backend

Tags: android

I have created an Android App with a Feedback Section. The user enters the feedback and I get it at my SQL database. There's a column in my SQL table which in which I write the reply to the feedback. I want to display a notification to the user when I write something in the 'reply' column of the SQL database table. What should I do? How should I go about it? If it involves using a broadcast receiver, give me relevant tutorials on that.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to the problem at:

http://simpleandroidtutorials.blogspot.in/2012/06/periodically-update-data-from-server-in.html

It's step by step guide for implementing what I want exactly.